# SAP HYBRIS [Y] : The import org.zkoss cannot be resolved

Tags: controller, widget, sap-commerce-cloud, zul, backoffice

I am creating a widget in backoffice on HYBRIS.

After the generation of the extension `trainingbackoffice` I added it in the `localxtension.xml` file as following :

```
<extensions>
<path dir='${HYBRIS_BIN_DIR}' autoload='false' />
<extension name='mcc' />
<extension name='adaptivesearchsolr' />
<extension name='adaptivesearchbackoffice' />
<extension name='adaptivesearchsamplesaddon' />
<extension name='commerceservicesbackoffice' />
<extension name='solrfacetsearchbackoffice' />
<extension name='solrserver' />
<!-- <extension name='yacceleratorcockpits' /> -->
<!-- <extension name='yacceleratorinitialdata' /> -->
<!-- <extension name='yacceleratorstorefront' /> -->
<extension name='ycommercewebservices' />
<extension name='ycommercewebservicestest' />
<extension name='electronicsstore' />
<extension name='apparelstore' />
<extension name='captchaaddon' />
<extension name='liveeditaddon' />
<extension name='acceleratorwebservicesaddon' />
<extension name='commerceorgsamplesaddon' />
<extension name='orderselfserviceaddon' />
<extension name='rulebuilderbackoffice' />
<extension name='couponbackoffice' />
<extension name='droolsruleengineservices' />
<extension name='couponfacades' />
<extension name='promotionenginesamplesaddon' />
<extension name='assistedservicestorefront' />
<extension name='assistedserviceyprofileaddon' />
<extension name='assistedservicecustomerinterestsaddon' />
<extension name='assistedservicepromotionaddon' />
<extension name='customerticketingaddon' />
<extension name='customersupportbackoffice' />
<extension name='eventtrackingwsaddon' />
<extension name='hybrisanalyticsaddon' />
<extension name='yprofileeventtrackingws' />
<extension name='yprofileeventadapter' />
<extension name='yprofileprocessadapter' />
<extension name='privacyoverlayeraddon' />
<extension name='yaasconfigurationbackoffice' />
<extension name='textfieldconfiguratortemplatebackoffice' />
<extension name='textfieldconfiguratortemplateaddon' />
<extension name='cmswebservices' />
<extension name='smarteditwebservices' />
<extension name='cmssmarteditwebservices' />
<extension name='permissionswebservices' />
<extension name='smarteditaddon' />
<extension name='cmssmartedit' />
<extension name='consignmenttrackingaddon' />
<extension name='consignmenttrackingmockaddon' />
<extension name='consignmenttrackingbackoffice' />
<extension name='notificationaddon' />
<extension name='customerinterestsaddon' />
<extension name='stocknotificationaddon' />
<extension name='configurablebundleaddon' />
<extension name='previewpersonalizationweb' />
<extension name='personalizationcmsweb' />
<extension name='personalizationsmartedit' />
<extension name='personalizationsampledataaddon' />
<extension name='personalizationyprofile' />
<extension name='personalizationpromotions' />
<extension name='personalizationpromotionsweb' />
<extension name='personalizationservicesbackoffice' />
<extension name='personalizationpromotionsbackoffice' />
<extension name='personalizationcmsbackoffice' />
<extension name='personalizationintegrationbackoffice' />
<extension name='assistedserviceatddtests' />
<extension name='promotionengineatddtests' />
<extension name='textfieldconfiguratortemplateatddtests' />
<extension name='configurablebundleatddtests' />
<extension name='configurablebundlecockpits' />
<extension name='pcmbackofficesamplesaddon' />


<extension name='mcc' />
<extension name="hmc" />


<extension name='trainingcockpits'/>
<extension name='trainingcore'/>
<extension name='trainingfacades'/>
<extension name='trainingfulfilmentprocess'/>
<extension name='traininginitialdata'/>
<extension name='trainingstorefront'/>
<extension name='trainingtest'/>

<extension name='trainingbackoffice'/>

</extensions>
```

and I created a controller for the widget as following :

```
 package org.training.widgets.mysearch;

 import java.util.List;

 import org.training.service.SearchService;
 import org.zkoss.zk.ui.event.Events;
 import org.zkoss.zk.ui.select.annotation.WireVariable;
 import org.zkoss.zul.Messagebox;
 import org.zkoss.zul.Textbox;

 import com.hybris.cockpitng.annotations.ViewEvent;
 import com.hybris.cockpitng.util.DefaultWidgetController;



 /* @author scharafi
 *
 */
 public class MySearchController extends DefaultWidgetController
 {
private Textbox searchInput;
@WireVariable
private SearchService searchService;

@ViewEvent(componentID = "searchBtn", eventName = Events.ON_CLICK)
public void doSearch() throws InterruptedException
{
    final List<String> result = searchService.search(searchInput.getText());
    Messagebox.show(result.get(0));
}

public Textbox getSearchInput()
{
    return searchInput;
}

public void setSearchInput(final Textbox searchInput)
{
    this.searchInput = searchInput;
}

public SearchService getSearchService()
{
    return searchService;
}

public void setSearchService(final SearchService searchService)
{
    this.searchService = searchService;
}
}
```

and I added the controller in definitions.xml as following :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes" ?>

<widget-definition id="org.training.widgets.mysearch" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="http://www.hybris.com/schema/cockpitng/widget-definition.xsd">

<controller class="org.training.widgets.mysearch.MySearchController"/>


<name>My Search</name>
<description>My own search widget.</description>
<defaultTitle>Search</defaultTitle>
<author>CHARAFI Saad</author>
<version>0.1</version>

</widget-definition>
```

After having run the command ant clean all the build does not pass.

And errors appear in the console as following :

```
[yjavac] 1. ERROR in C:\hybris\hybris\bin\custom\trainingbackoffice\src\org\training\widgets\mysearch\MySearchController.java (at line 6)
   [yjavac]     import org.zkoss.zk.ui.event.Events;
   [yjavac]            ^^^^^^^^^
   [yjavac]     The import org.zkoss cannot be resolved
```

The error is applied on all imports of zul

**UPDATE :**

Here is `extensioninfo.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
<extensioninfo xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="extensioninfo.xsd">

<extension abstractclassprefix="Generated" classprefix="Trainingbackoffice" managername="TrainingbackofficeManager" managersuperclass="de.hybris.platform.jalo.extension.Extension" name="trainingbackoffice" usemaven="false">

    <!-- you should add all required extensions to this list, except platform extensions which are automatically required -->
    <!-- <requires-extension name="cms"/> -->

    <requires-extension name="backoffice"/>


    <coremodule generated="true" manager="org.training.jalo.TrainingbackofficeManager" packageroot="org.training"/>

    <meta key="backoffice-module" value="true"/>

</extension>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your class is defined in a global context, but ZK Framework is only available in a backoffice context.

The extension structure:

- `src` ← global context (all extensions can use it)
- `backoffice/src` ← backoffice context (only backoffice extensions can use it)

Move your classes which depend on ZK Framework from `src` to `backoffice/src`.

---

Why ZK Framework is only available in the backoffice context? Backoffice is a web application and can use libraries located in `lib` and `web/webroot/WEB-INF/lib` directories. ZK classes are located in the `web/webroot/WEB-INF/lib` directory. Backoffice extensions (`backoffice/src`) are loaded in the web context and that is the reason why they can use ZK Framework. Classes defined in `src` can use only libraries located in the `lib` directory, so ZK classes are not available.

Comment: but I would like to understand why ZK Framework is available only is a backoffice context.

Comment: I extended the answer.

Answer (score 2):

How you have created your custom backoffice extension. Have you used `ybackoffice` template ?

The problem seems to be related with dependency issue. Kindly verify your extensioninfo.xml file. You should have dependency with backoffice extension.

extensioninfo.xml ...

```
<requires-extension name="backoffice"/>
```

Comment: Thank u for ur reply, yes I used the template ybackoffice. In trainingbackoffice extensioninfo.xml the dependency exist.
But in the tag extension the usemaven attribute is false.

Comment: I added extensioninfos.xml in the post

Comment: Then issue will be your file location. As suggested by @agabrys, move your controller file from src folder to backoffice/src folder. It must solved the problem.

Comment: Thank you for your cooperation problem solved, but i would like why ZK framework  is available only is a backoffice context

Answer (score 0):

You can check in your setup if zkoss library is present and has not been deleted by mistake during build or something. Sometimes this creates problem with import. If this is the problem you need to add all missing libraries in your setup post which you will be able to proceed.Hope this solves your problem!